# Composite DisplayMember for ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I need to display multiple pieces of data in a combobox, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's the code I'm trying to make work:

```
        innerBox.DisplayMember = @"t => t.TenantName + ""\t"" + t.Property.PropertyName + ""\t"" + t.RentalUnit.UnitNumber ";
```

But it doesn't work, this does though:

```
        innerBox.DisplayMember = @"t => t.TenantName";
```

How can I get the composite one to work?

Comment: what is the type of innerBox variable?

Comment: @Rohit: I assume it's a ComboBox

Comment: never knew winform combobox can take something like that in display name

Comment: @SLaks he claims that it works

Comment: @Rohit, @SLaks, the second example does work, you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Instead, you should add a property to your underlying objects.

Answer (score 2):

DisplayMember can contain only single property name! If you want composite output, you should subscribe to [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format.aspx) event and compose output string in code.

Comment: I think the Format event messes with my OwnerDraw DrawItem event.

Comment: @Malfist, If your have owner draw combobox then why you bothering about DisplayMember? You can draw anything you wish, including any composite data string.

Comment: Yes I want to show formatted in DisplayMember of combobox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have "[code] [text]' in DisplayMember and solved it by adding a property using linq:

```
var actionCodes = pps.GetAllActionCodes();
if (actionCodes != null)
{
    var actionCodesNew = (from c in actionCodes
                                select new
                                {
                                    c.Code,
                                    c.Text,
                                    CodeAndDesc = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.Code, c.Text).Trim()
                                }).ToArray();
            comboBox.Items.AddRange(actionCodesNew);
            comboBox.DisplayMember = "CodeAndDesc";
        }
}
```

Works ok when performance is not an issue. :)

Comment: In order to retreive the combobox.SelectedValue at a later stage you'll need to change the line 'comboBox.Items.AddRange(actionCodesNew)' to 'combobox.DataSource=actionCodesNew' and set comboBox.ValueMember="Code". This makes c.Code the valuemember.